# Refactoring a require.config.js file...?

Tags: javascript, angularjs, requirejs, karma-runner, gulp

My application has 3 separate `require.config.js` files because the app needs different configurations when running two types of karma/jasmine tests.

This means whenever I add a new component to the app, I have to update each `require.config.js` file. I'm wondering if there's a way to extract common settings from those files into a single config file, and then somehow injecting that into each of the `require.config.js` files?

I was thinking of maybe using `gulp`, but I'm hoping for a method that doesn't depend on a gulp task.

I see that the karma/require files are using `modules.export`, is there a way to use that structure to do this?

Answer (score 1):

To avoid duplicating require configuration my setup is as follow:

I've got a config.js file with all my app dependancies.

It looks like :

```
require.config({
    paths: {
     //all my paths
    },
    shim: {
     // all shim
    }
});
```

In my app main.js I require it and then launch my app:

```
require(['./config'], function(){
    require(['initializer'], function (initialize){
        initialize();
    });
});
```

In my test main.js I import config, add some dependancies, and launch the test :

```
require(['../../www/js/config'], function (){

require.config({
// !! Karma serves files from '/base'
// (in this case, it is the root of the project /your-project/app/js)
    paths: {
        angularMock: '../components/angular-mocks/angular-mocks'
    },
    shim: {
        angularMock: {
            deps: ['angular']
        },
    },
    deps: testsFiles
});

require([
'jquery',
"../../www/js/initializer",
], function($, initialize) {
    $(document).ready(function() {
        initialize();
        window.FB = {
            init: function() {

            }
        };
        window.__karma__.start();
    });

});
});
```

Answer (score 0):

1. Create a config which requires all your common dependencies and Namespace your dependencies i.e. myApp.components.views.view1, myApp.components.models.model1 etc.
2. Return this namespace.
3. In your specialised configs just import your common dependencies file. Since you are returning the namespace, myApp should contain the common.
4. Import your specialised dependencies and add them myApp (or not, depends how you want to do it).

Hope that helps.